# Python in miniconda keeps breaking after a few days of installing miniconda

Tags: python, conda, miniconda, python-3.10

I'm working on Linux and installed miniconda3 on my scratch, which is not the default for the conda installation, which is why I don't run `conda init` but my bashrc file sources `. "/scratch/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"` and exports the path (`export PATH="/scratch/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"`). This used to work like this for a year without having any issues. Since like a month, I have to re-install miniconda repeatedly after a few days because I suddenly get the error (the few days until that happens it works as it used to):

```
Could not find platform independent libraries <prefix>
Consider setting $PYTHONHOME to <prefix>[:<exec_prefix>]
Python path configuration:
  PYTHONHOME = (not set)
  PYTHONPATH = (not set)
  program name = '/scratch/miniconda3/bin/python'
  isolated = 0
  environment = 1
  user site = 1
  import site = 1
  sys._base_executable = '/scratch/miniconda3/bin/python'
  sys.base_prefix = '/scratch/miniconda3'
  sys.base_exec_prefix = '/scratch/miniconda3'
  sys.platlibdir = 'lib'
  sys.executable = '/scratch/miniconda3/bin/python'
  sys.prefix = '/scratch/miniconda3'
  sys.exec_prefix = '/scratch/miniconda3'
  sys.path = [
    '/scratch/miniconda3/lib/python310.zip',
    '/scratch/miniconda3/lib/python3.10',
    '/scratch/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload',
  ]
Fatal Python error: init_fs_encoding: failed to get the Python codec of the filesystem encoding
Python runtime state: core initialized
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/scratch/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/encodings/__init__.py", line 31, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'codecs'
```

Any suggestions I found online were unfortunately not of any help so far. I also tried to execute Python from my miniconda by running `/scratch/miniconda3/bin/python`, which gives me the same error message as above. So it seems like the Python version within my miniconda breaks after a few days but I have no idea why.